# Datadog metric gets round to 2 decimal places

Tags: python, metrics, datadog

I am using a python package `datadog_api_client` to publish data to a metric to Datadog. The code looks like:

```
        now = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
        metric_name = 'test.metric.count'
        with ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
            # Create an instance of the API class
            api_instance = metrics_api.MetricsApi(api_client)
            body = MetricsPayload(
                series=[
                    Series(
                        host="test_tool",
                        interval=20,
                        metric=metric_name,
                        points=[
                            Point([now, float(1127023]),
                        ],
                        tags=metric_tags,
                        type="count",
                    ),
                ],
            )  # MetricsPayload

            try:
                # Submit metrics
                api_response = api_instance.submit_metrics(body)
                print(f"Metric: {metric_name} : {api_response}")
            except ApiException as e:
                raise Exception(f"Exception when calling MetricsApi->submit_metrics: {e}")
```

When I run this piece of code Datadog publishes the metric value as 1.13M which is not completely accurate. I checked a lot of documentation but cannot find any attribute that I am missing which can be added to remove the precision.

Can anyone please help me in getting the numbers?